# Visual Studio project type for client-side javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Could somebody advise me on which project type should I use to develop client side of web-based app (HTML + JavaScript) for Visual Studio 2013?

I tried to create New, Web Site, ASP.NET Empty Web site, then manually added all .js files to the project, but this is not exactly what I need, because I am working on a client-side code only, and the Web server is not IIS.

Of course, when a script error occurs, I can select “Debug using selected debugger”, manually choose my project and jump into debugging. However, this is only a half-solution.
First, I cannot start debugger with F5 – it launches web page connected to local IIS instead.
Second, I have duplicate source trees in solution explorer- the debugger does not match my source files with files loaded with web pages.

I have also tried New, Other project types, Visual Studio solution, Add existing Web site, and played with Start Options, but without much success too. It launches page in IE, but with script debugging disabled (???), and it does not start the debugger anyway.

Is there an appropriate project type to write and debug JavaScript for IE?

PS: When installing VS, I selected C++ development, as my primary settings, which might hide some useful Web development features. And I would prefer not to change this.

UPDATE: Problem #1 (starting with F5) was solved by setting IE as default Web browser (I have used Firefox). After specifying “Specific page” in Start options F5 starts the page under debugger.
Is it possible to debug scripts under IE, leaving my favorite browser as default? If I specify “Start External program” and set “iexplore.exe” with page url, it launches the page but does not allow me to debug it.

Comment: Have you tried the Typescript template (if you are on Update 2 it's built in, otherwise you need to install it)...

Another option may be to start with an Windows 8 app template and trim that down...

Comment: I have tried Typescript template, but it has the same drawbacks.
Setting IE as default browser actually helped (see my update), but I am still looking for another solution.

Comment: Just use a good browser like Mozilla Firefox or Google Chrome, they have a builtin console and debugger. Open once the debugger, press F5 for reloading and F8 for continuing from a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

you have a bunch of questions in here, but let me try answer them.

1. To develop client-side of web-based app, Create an `ASP.NET Empty Web site` and manually add `HTML + JavaScript`
2. If the Web Server is not IIS, then you can change, `right-click` on your project in VS-2013, and in `properties`,check `Web` properties.
3. `To Debug` your HTML and JavaScript in `IE`, then follow this:

   you have to enable `Script debugging` in IE as follow:
   [image]

   let, if you have a function named `FirstFunction()` in your `HTML page` then

   ```
   <script type="script/javascript">
   function FirstFunction()
   {
       debugger;
   alert("Debugging now");

   }
   </script>
   ```

Comment: This is exactly what I did. And "debugger" instruction works fine. The problem was how to start debugging from the first line of code, without attaching to it manually.

Comment: OK in Internet Explorer, using Developer tools, mark `breakpoint` on the first line of code, and the `refresh` the page